# Checking isset($_POST["submit"]) twice not working

Tags: php, loops

I am connecting to an API to post file and retrieve data about the file. The problem is that the API returns half data with status 'queued'. I want my script to keep checking every 10 seconds. So I am using sleep(10) with loop for it. But, I want to display a 'loading..' message until then. But it doesn't happen until loop is completed and status is changed to 'completed'.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo "loading..";
}

// curl request here

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    while($status == 'queued') {
        sleep(10);
        // curl request again and check status
    }
    if($status == 'completed') {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Shouldn't 'loading..' text be displayed first and then page keep loading until status changes to 'completed'. Why is that not happening.

Comment: This "transitional" approach would be better suited to a Javascript AJAX PHP request so your output update is handled by Javascript, because that's what it does while PHP does the data collection under the covers.

Comment: There is a limit for maximal computation time, aren’t you exceeding it?

Comment: Remember, whatever you do in PHP will not be shown on the browser until the PHP code completes. You may want to do this in Javascript. You may also be able to call the API from javascript

Comment: @Martin I was really hoping to do this via PHP alone.

Comment: @RatajS Yes it gives 500 internal server error after a while but that's another issue that I will solve later on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not working even with jQuery either. I put `$('#content-container').html('loading');` on top of php page but the page loads entirely first. And then this text gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display a 'loading..' message until then. But it doesn't happen until loop is completed and status is changed to 'completed'.

PHP normally has output buffering enabled for 4096 bytes, and even without output buffering an intermediate server might buffer.

So a command like:

```php
echo "loading..";
```

does actually the output from the scripts perspective, but it must not automatically mean that the browser will receive it. Our educated guess here is that this is what you experience.

To be more "pushy", you can switch to the [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and send in fragments. In PHP you trigger this with the [`flush()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function:

```php
echo "loading..";
flush();
```

Some browsers *may* still refuse to display it, until they have received a specific number of bytes, checkout the [`flush();` documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) for some details.

E.g. if output buffering is enabled, it requires to flush the output buffer first, then flush:

```php
echo "loading..";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Also if intermediate servers are buffering, this is also out of control from PHP's perspective. Dive into the documentation page to get the most out of it.

Comment: Didn't work in any of the browsers.

Comment: Yes, as you might have read out of the answer this is _complicated_. Many components are involved at this level of HTTP and from your comment I'm not sure how deep you're willing to go into it. As usual alternatives exist, have you put client-side scripting and more modern web-apis into consideration? An entry-level one is [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource), there is also standard [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You'll need to do a bit of conceptual work, but I think exploring this a bit gives you more options.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I will look into these options.

Comment: @user17281121: I can't promise you a rose garden. It can be that the more you look into this stuff, the more complicated it gets. Just saying. Also updated the answer, if you didn't, add the ob_flush();, I've taken that as well from the documentation page. Try to understand even the basics, you will then benefit more even from the alternatives.